# UIMenuController with Images

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, menuitem, uimenucontroller

Can anyone provide an example of how to display images in a UIMenuController? In iBooks, if you select some text and then choose Highlight from the displayed menu, it will switch to a contextual highlight menu that has images in it.

[image: iBooks highlight menu with images]

I am already able to create a menu that has custom titles and actions, as describe in the [UIMenuControllerClass Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenuitem). I've come up empty on displaying images though.

Comment: Have you tried sample provided by apple ???

Comment: I have been through the sample projects referenced in the UIMenuControllerClass Reference. I have not found any that include an image. If I have overlooked something, please provide a link to the sample you're referring to.